# I was able to change lock screen wallpaper but can't change of that screen which comes after sleep on MacBook pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, sleep-wake

I was looking some ways to customise my mac, and I saw a way to change lock seer wallpaper by keeping the same name "com.apple.desktop.admin.png" as of the automated lock screen wallpaper
[image]

[image: When i opened my mac after shutdown]
When i opened my mac after shutdown

[image]
I got that blurred image after i closed my mac's flap or lid and even by pressing sleep in the apple menu, how can I change it also?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to fix it instead of going through your cache is to use a free utility called [Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html).

It will enable you to change it very easily to whichever photo you like! [image: OnyxLoginbackgroundchange]

Answer (score 0):

I that blurred image is just the desktop image, so if you set that to what you want under System Preferences > Desktop and Screensaver it will appear as you want (blurred.)

In Mojave they stopped the blurring (from what I can tell)